# positioning menu for flexible page

Tags: html, css, menu, positioning, footer

I am designing a centered page but my menu is not exactly centered. It is a bit close to the right side. I couldn't see why it is like that.Could you please help?

Thanks for any help.

CSS

```
body {

         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         text-align:center;
         background: #ffffff }

div.wrap {
         max-width:800px;
         min-width:400px;
         margin: 0px auto;
         border: 1px dashed red; }

div.inner-wrap {
         overflow: auto;        
         margin: 30px;
         border: 1px dashed #222; }
div.header {
        padding-top: 1pc;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        color: #000000;}

     div.menu { 
        list-style:none; 
        margin:0; 
        padding:0; 
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        background:#FBB117;} 
     div.menu ul{ 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        width: 100px 
        padding:0;
        display:inline-block;} 
     div.menu li{ 
        display:inline; } 
     div.menu li a{ 
        text-decoration:none; 
        padding:7px 0; 
        width:100px; 
        background:#FBB117; 
        color:#4C4646; 
        float:left; 
        text-align:center; }  
     div.menu li a:hover{ 
        background:#a2b3a1; 
        color:#000 } 

div.content {
         padding-top: 2pc;
         text-align:left;
         margin-left: 50px;
         margin-right: 50px;
         color: #000000 }

div.content p {
    color: #493831;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0;}

     div.sidebar {
         margin-right: 15%;
         padding-top: 2pc;
         text-align:center;
         float: right;
         width: 200px;
         color: #000000;
         list-style:none; }
     div.sidebar ul{
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto; 
         margin-top: 3px;
         margin-bottom: 3px;
         padding:0;
         list-style: none;
         display:inline-block;  }
     div.sidebar li{
         display:inline; }
     div.sidebar li a{ 
        text-decoration:none; 
        padding:10px 0; 
        width:100%; 
        background:#FBB117; 
        color:#4C4646; 
        float:right; 
        text-align:center; 
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}  
     div.sidebar li a:hover{ 
        background:#a2b3a1; 
        color:#000 }
```

HTML code is here:

```
<body>
      <div class="wrap">
      <div class="inner wrap">
      <div class="header">
           <img src="realimg1.jpg" class="real" alt="king">
           <h1>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
           <ul>

              <li><a href="link1.html">xx</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1.html">xxxx</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxx</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1.html">xx</a></li>
              <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxx</a></li>

           </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
          <p>
          <img src="img1.jpg" class="bw" alt="king">
          The CC is one of the oldest continually operating chess club in
          the Southern Hemisphere.We can proudly boast that we have been open daily since 1990 and we inted to
          maintain that tradition. On any night, you will find members of the club playing casual games or
          participating in one of our manly regulary scheduled tournaments. We are family club, and offer competition and
          instruction suitable for chess players of all skill levels and age groups.</p>
          <p>No other club in texas can boast a history so rich. Winning the club champion championships is your
          chance to get amongst these greats, and be immortalized foreve on the honow boards.</p>
          <p>Throughout the year,  Chess Club 'traditional time control' FIDE rated events form, whereby
          a player's scores from all 9 events will add up to form a grand prix score at the end of the year.The tournaments included are:
          Australia Day Weekender, Chess Club Championship,ANZAC Day Weekender, City Of Brisbane Open, Edwin Malitis Memorial, Chess Club Open , Chess Club Cup Weekender

      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
           <ul>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxxxxxx</a></li>
           <li><a href="link1.html">xxxxxxxx</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>


      </div>
      </div>

   </body>​
```

Comment: We need the corresponding HTML code. Please post a fiddle for example or a link to an online page

Comment: I am not sure how to save fiddle and send the link. I added html code too. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @pepsicode the `save` button in jsfiddle normally work pretty well at saving.

Comment: fiddle codes http://jsfiddle.net/BpmUp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sidebar margin 0 or auto and remove float because you want to this center

as like this

```
div.sidebar {

         padding-top: 2pc;
         text-align:center;

         width: 200px;
         color: #000000;
             list-style:none;
margin:0 auto;        
}
```

Livedemo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/wFQdj/

Comment: Think @pepsicode is talking about the main menu at the top of the page, not the sidebar menu.

Comment: Hey  @pepsicode your top navi is already centered http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/wFQdj/1/